# Optimization of getting leading/trailing entries

Tags: postgresql, relational-database

I am trying to get the leading or trailing x entries from a table to a specific id. My current attempt does do work quite well BUT it looks quite clunky and I would like to know if there is a way to improve it.

```
WITH tempTable AS ( SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY created DESC) AS RN from byali.posts)
SELECT * from tempTable as nb1 WHERE RN IN (SELECT nb2.RN+i
             FROM tempTable AS nb2
             CROSS JOIN (SELECT a.n as i FROM generate_series(-10,-1) as a(n)) n
             WHERE nb2.id='188d9b6b-e398-407d-9cf4-e75ff121c32a')
```

This will select the 10 posts before the entry with the id

> 188d9b6b-e398-407d-9cf4-e75ff121c32a

Table Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE byali.posts
(
    id uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    title text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    message text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    created timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
    CONSTRAINT posts_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

And sample data:

```
insert into byali.posts (title,message,created) VALUES ('title1','message1','2018-02-11 17:00:56.349611+01'),('title2','message2','2018-02-13 12:22:54.432413+01'),('title3','message3','2018-02-13 14:38:51.997999+01')
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and table structures. Your query is unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If created column is unique you can get 10 posts before the entry with the id = 188d9b6b-e398-407d-9cf4-e75ff121c32a using following query:

```
select *
from byali.posts
where created < (select created
                 from byali.posts
                 where id = '188d9b6b-e398-407d-9cf4-e75ff121c32a')
order by created desc
limit 10;
```

10 posts after the entry with the id = 188d9b6b-e398-407d-9cf4-e75ff121c32a

```
select *
from byali.posts
where created > (select created
                 from byali.posts
                 where id = '188d9b6b-e398-407d-9cf4-e75ff121c32a')
order by created
limit 10;
```